# Efficient synchronization of querying an array of resources

Tags: java, synchronization

There is a list of N resources, each of them can be queried by at most a single thread at a time.

There are several threads that need to do the same thing at approximately the same time: query each of the resources (each thread has a different query), in arbitrary order, and collect the responses.

If each thread loops over the resources in the same order, from 0 to N-1, then they will probably have to wait for each other, which is not efficient.

I thought of letting the threads loop over the resources in a random permutation, but this seems too complex and also not so efficient, for example, for 2 resources and 2 threads, in half the cases they will choose the same order and wait for each other.

Is there a simple and more efficient way to solve this?

Comment: How big does the number of threads tend to be (relative to *N*)?

Comment: Currently they are both quite small (N is at most 8, the number of threads is 2-4). In the future, the number of threads may grow.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, my answer to this is that there is not. You have no control over the threads and the order they access the resources, and, most of all (which is the entire point of synchronizing) you don't know how they will be scheduled for execution. Even trying to get them to access to free resources would have unpredictable results, because last thread created could be scheduled first.

The only thing that comes to my mind is partitioning. That is, dividing the resources and/or threads to access/be accessed in parts. Note that this is not a simple issue: As you said, having less threads and less resources would increase chances that a thread tries to access an already locked resource.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think the other way around. The key is to prevent starvation of the resources, i.e. minimize the time the resource is not processing requests when it can. Generally queues are useful here.

Given that you have at most 8 different resources, I'd give each resource its own thread and a queue. The querying threads will first put all their requests onto these queues and then wait, while the resource consumes from this queue. This way, the resource will be saturated with  requests and starvation is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the resource from the list when its in use, so each thread does:

- remove resource from list
- process it
- put it back

obviously list access needs to be synchronized. This way you will never have 2 threads trying to use the same resource.

Comment: Interesting, but then what happens if thread A starts querying resource #1, then thread B queries all other resources and finishes, and then thread A returns resource #1 - how will thread B know that it has to wait for resource #1?

Comment: well "it depends" - you could have collection that allows a thread to see what resources there are without being able to act on them, and a separate 'available' set. But exactly how you set it up will depend on how often the set changes and so on.